# Security of changing password in vue's component

Tags: laravel, security, vue.js

I made an component in my SPA application to changing user's password. All my code that is working correctly looks like this:

method which is getting data from form with v-model:

```
export default {
        data(){
            return {
                password: {
                    old_password: '',
                    new_password: '',
                    repeat_password: ''
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changePassword() {
                axios.post('api/change_password', this.password).then( response=> {
                    this.password = {
                        old_password: '',
                        new_password: '',
                        repeat_password: '' 
                    };
                    console.log(response.data.message);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

then in my controller i receive data and I am validating them in this way:

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $get_user = Auth::user();

        $user = User::find($get_user->id);

        $current_password = $get_user->password;

        if (Hash::check($request->input('old_password'), $get_user->password) && ($request->input('new_password') == $request->input('repeat_password'))) {

            $user->update([
                'password' => Hash::make($request->input('new_password'))
            ]);

            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Password updated'
            ]);

        }
}
```

My question to you guys is that: Is this method secure? If not could you explain how to do this in better way?

Comment: What hashing do you use? Only use strong hashing algorithms for the password.

Comment: As far as i can see its bcrypt.
[Laravel Hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing)

Comment: OK. Then I think you are fine. Basically you have two things to consider: data in transit (typical way to protect is TLS) and data at rest (typical way is hashing and bcrypt is a good way to do so)

Answer (score 2):

As you are sending sensitive data over the network, you must use SSL.

> SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) is a technology to encrypt communications between the user and the web server. It helps to prevent hacker attacks that are based on eavesdropping. When you use a web page that is protected by SSL, you see a padlock icon that assures you that the page is secure.